# Global font size setting for captions

Tags: floats, captions, grouping

Dear $\LaTeX$ community,

I was wondering if it were possible to assign a specific font size for the caption grouping for figures and tables?

Comment: If you use for captions the `caption` packages (recommended), than you can set caption style for all captions (font size and shapes,  formatting etc). For more specific answer you need to provide some complete example (that can be compiled) of your document.